# TextView And Its Content

Tags: ios, swift

I want to place information text in main scene of the application. When ı place a text view, its content starts at the middle. There is a between the text and top boundary of the TextView.

How can I make the text start at the first line of the TextView ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `contentOffset` property of `textView` to zero like

```
textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
 textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```